# (Discord.py-rewrite) Command executes without errors, but doesn't work

Tags: python, discord.py

Hey so for some reason this code doesn't send any message when I execute it, it doesn't throw any errors. I'm thinking it's something with the embed, but I can't seem to figure out what's the problem. Any help? Thank you.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import json
import requests
import random
from random import randrange
from random import randint
import asyncio
import time
from itertools import cycle
import math


@client.command(aliases=["hacker", "hacking", "hax"])
async def hack(ctx):
    diffrent_hacks_msg = [
        "hacked the goverment and earned",
        "hacked the FBI and earned",
        "hacked a bank and earned",
        "hacked a charity and earned",
        "hacked the presidents bank account and earned",
        "hacked a normal citizen and earned",
        "hacked a crypto coin and earned",
        "hacked the CIA and earned",
        "hacked a police officer and earned",
        "hacked the police departament and earned",
        "hacked a bank truck and earned",
        "hacked the IRS and earned",
        "hacked a friend and earned",
        "hacked Google and earned",
        "hacked Youtube and earned",
        "hacked Twitch and earned",
        "hacked a government official and earned",
        "hacked Walter White and earned",
    ]

    caughtmanmsg = ["FBI", "CIA", "police", "government", "IRS"]

    randomhackmsg = random.choice(diffrent_hacks_msg)
    randomcaught = random.choice(caughtmanmsg)
    earned = random.int(1, 2500000)
    hacksucc = random.int(1, 7)
    hackfail = randomhackmsg.replace(" and earned", "")

    if hacksucc == 1:
        embedhs = discord.Embed(
            title=f"YO HOW?",
            description=f"{ctx.author.mention} {randomhackmsg} {earned} DKC!",
            color=0xCFCFCF,
            timestamp=ctx.message.created_at,
        )
        embedhs.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author.name}")
        await ctx.send(embed=embedhs)
    elif hacksucc != 1:
        embedhf = discord.Embed(
            title=f"Unlucky...",
            description=f"{ctx.author.mention} {hackfail}, but got caught by the {randomcaught}...",
            color=0xCFCFCF,
            timestamp=ctx.message.created_at,
        )
        embedhf.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author.name}")
        await ctx.send(embed=embedhf)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as `random.int`, you're looking for `random.randint`

```py
earned = random.randint(1, 2500000)
hacksucc = random.randint(1, 7)
```

Comment: Oh my god im dumb, thank you so much, i dont even know how i could just miss that